# Javascript to automatically zoom in with a browser on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a java application which is 500x400 px my iPhones width is much greater then 400px, after the site loads I need to manually zoom into the application. Is there a javascript to automatically zoom the window so that the width of my screen being displayed is 400px, secondly is there a way to disable scrolling :) 
Thank you so much!

Comment: So basically script to zoom in automatically on certain resolution right?

Comment: yes @vaibhav thats exactly what I want :)

Comment: no need for js. set width to 100% and set overflow to hidden in css

Comment: No, but wouldn't that create the canvas application to become un-proportional? Or make the canvas bigger then I want?? @Winchestro

Comment: @reidjako there are **few** cases where you need js, you'd be amazed how much you can accomplish with pure css, despite the "language" itself being horrible :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-100px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">
```

Using a meta tag got it to work

Answer (score 2):

Check out CSS3 Media Queries. They allow you to include stylesheets depending on the browser's viewport's size. And to disable scrolling u could set the scroll to hidden.

**Code to disable scroll.**

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
})
```

Also by using js u could detect what platform u r rendering your application and then use zoom to zoom in accordingly.

**Example for mozilla**:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla){
            var step = 0.02;
            currFFZoom += step; 
            $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
        } else {
            var step = 2;
            currIEZoom += step;
            $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        }
```

Comment: How would I do this for mobile safari? So for iPhone :) @Vaibhav

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser try seeing this. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Its not a matter of detecting, its a matter of scaling, this application is on the mobile site all ready. The issue is, is that my iPhone 5s's width is about 600, more I think. But I want it to zoom into 400px width. It will only be used on my phone with safari. Thank you :)

Comment: i prefer feature detection over platform detection but nice answer. +1